# Do images in 'user-images.githubusercontent.com' have expire time?

Tags: github

I'm servicing a blog using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

The blog service has many images files to upload, so I needed a repository that stores images.

While searching for a repository, I found a method using github-issues.

I capture my image first and then paste to github-issues body. It will be changed to a markdown image tag that has an image url like:

```
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/{path}/{filename})
```

My question is: does the image stored in `githubusercontent.com` have an expire time?

If the image has an expire time, it will not appear on my blog later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, Github had a response.

> These images can be removed by staff in the event of a Terms of Service violation, however they do ***not have a set expiration*** and are not deletable by customers.

Ref: https://github.community/t/does-user-images-githubusercontent-expires/129292

As for the aforementioned Terms of Service, I think it may be found here:
[GitHub Terms of Service](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that they aren't deleted or removed, especially since their in issues. You could always source them in the repository for the blog - in an `/assets/images/` directory or something.

Comment: Yeah I think so. but I'm little bit uneasy

Comment: That's perfectly fine. If you want to be 100% sure, just upload them to the site directly :)